# Android sqlite rawquery selection args problems

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to run use rawquery to run a query with an alias on the primary key to make it _id so that I can use the SimpleCursorAdapter, this is what I have:

```
String sel = DatabaseListDB.COLUMN_DATABASE_NAME;
Cursor results = db.rawQuery("SELECT ? as _id FROM DatabaseList", 
    new String[] {sel});
```

In my SqlLiteHelperClass

```
public static final String COLUMN_DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
```

is the column name I want and my primary key.  The problem is when I run this query the results come up with 'databaseName' as the values in the table instead of the actual values.
I can run the query as

```
Cursor results = db.rawQuery("SELECT databaseName as _id FROM DatabaseList", 
    null);
```

and it works fine and I have no idea why I cant use the selectionargs properly.  Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: you need to see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) what exactly selectionargs means WHERE condtion in SQL query

Comment: you'll want to have an _id column named _id if you are using any kind of cursor adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `developer.android.com`, you only can put "?" on where clause, not for columns you want to query:

- selectionArgs:    You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

Answer (score 2):

`?` is supposed to use for **WHERE** arguments. In your case, you should simply alter your query as:

```
Cursor results = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT %s as _id FROM DatabaseList", sel));
```

Comment: Oh I see, thank you, why is that though?  Whats the point of using them for the where part of a query instead of doing it the same way you did the rest of the query?

Comment: To support `?`, one of the reason i know is to avoid [malicious sql injection](http://www.imperva.com/resources/glossary/sql_injection.html) and also automatically handle the input of primitives.